# what is$ \sqrt{8i}$

Tags: complex-numbers

Very simple question with an answer that I cannot understand:

I have $\sqrt{8i}$, which, I suppose, is the same as $\sqrt{\sqrt{-64}}$.
How come that $2+2i$ is the same as $\sqrt{8i}$?

My understanding is that $\sqrt{8i}$ is the same as:
(a) $\sqrt{2^3i}$
OR
(b) $2\sqrt{2i}$

I'm pretty sure (a) is correct and (b) might also be correct, but how can you get from there to $2+2i$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you need to know what is $\sqrt{i}$ first. It seems to me that you can find it in the site cause it was certainly asked before here.

Comment: Every complex number can be put in the form $a+bi$. Set $(a+bi)^2=8i$ and try solving for $a$ and $b$ (each which must be real). In general polar form of numbers is useful.

Comment: Multiplying complex numbers means multiplying absolute values and adding angles, i.e. rotating.  The currently "accepted" answer to this question ignores the simple geometry.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(a+bi)^2=(a+bi)(a+bi)=a^2-b^2+2abi\implies \sqrt{a^2-b^2+2abi}=a+bi$
and for conjugate $(a-bi)^2=(a-bi)(a-bi)=a^2+b^2-2abi\implies \sqrt{a^2+b^2-2abi}=a-bi$
Now if we find $a$ and $b$ satisfy appropriate equotation:
For $(a+bi)^2$:
$a^2-b^2+2abi=8i$. This is valid for any $a=b$ where $2ab=8$, or 
$2a^2=8 \implies a=\pm\sqrt{4}=\pm{2} = b$. Here exists two numbers:
First $$\sqrt{8i}=2+2i$$ and second $$\sqrt{8i}=-2-2i$$
For $(a-bi)^2$:
$a^2+b^2-2abi=8i$. Because $a^2 \ge 0$ and $b^2 \ge 0$, there does not exists solution.

Comment: Your conjugate should be -b^2, not +b^2. The reason being that its -bi*-bi = bi*bi = -b^2. The correct interpretation also of a^2-b^2 is that a = b or a=-b. In the first case ab=4 means a=-b is not possible. In your conjugate example ab=-4 and thus a=-b. It gives the same answer whether you use a+bi or a-bi, its just the sign of b is changed.

Comment: This answer also avoids the geometry.

Comment: Upvoters: why the upvote?

Answer (score 5):

one way to see it is there exists some $z$ such that $z^2=8i$, now sub $z=a+ib$ to get $a^2-b^2+2iab=8i$, equate real and the imaginary parts, solve the simultaneous equation. if you know about the exponential form of complex numbers, this problem can be solved even quicker but I suspect you haven't learnt that yet. By the way be careful in the above statement when you say $\sqrt{\sqrt{}}$, personally its not evidently clear your allowing both the $\sqrt{}$ values to be accounted as it seems your accounting for the positive only, remember the $\sqrt{}$ of negatives don't exist in the reals but does in complex numbers.

Comment: Assuming that 8i = 0+8i, then I will have: a^2-b^2 = 0  and 2iab = 8i; I can solve the first and conclude that a^2 = b^2; then I go to the second, and if I solve for a, I get a = 4/b; if I solve for b I get b = 4/a. At this point I substitute a=4/b to a^2 = b^2 and I get (4/b)^2 = b^2 which is 16/b^2 = b^2. From there I multiply both sides for b^2 and I get 16 = b^4, which means that b +/- 2 (and the same applies for a, I suppose). At this point I undestand that 4-4+2*2*2i = 8i, but I still don't get how to arrive to sqrt(8i) = 2+2i :(

Comment: 8i=0+8i, dont assume that, its the complex representation. Now yes you have a^2=b^2 which means a=modb, and yes with the second equation you have a=4/b, sub that into the first equation and multiply by b^2 to get b^4=16, this implies b=plus or minus 2, then for each value of b, check the value of a, you will get + and - (2+2i). Remember the idea of doing this is that a,b are real, so essentially we are solving this problem by going to equations with real solutions for a and b, as a and b are defined to be real.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: $(1+i)^2=1+2i+i^2=2i\qquad\qquad$

Answer (score 4):

let $$x+iy=\sqrt{8i}$$
$$(x+iy)^2={8i}$$
$$x^2-y^2+2xyi=0+8i$$
compare real and imaginary parts of both sides:
$x^2-y^2=0\;; 2xy=8$
$$x^2-y^2=0$$
square both sides
$$\implies (x^2-y^2)^2 =0\implies (x^2+y^2)^2-(2xy)^2=0$$
$$\implies (x^2+y^2)^2=64 \implies (x^2+y^2)=\pm 8 $$
since sum of square of two real no. can't be negative so
$$x^2+y^2=8\text{ and }x^2-y^2=0$$
solving these two eqn will give $x=y=\pm 2 $

so $$\sqrt {8i}=\pm 2(1+i)\implies 2+2i,-2-2i$$

Comment: This answer obscures all of the geometry.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I don't get what you want to say

Comment: See my answer.  This answer doesn't say that multiplication of complex numbers consists of adding angles and multiplying lengths.

Comment: I wrote the thing which I learnt.And I don't think my answer is incorrect.

Comment: It's not incorrect, but it's useful to be aware of the geometry.

Comment: @MichaelHardy I fully agree with your push for geometrical solutions (such as yours, +1). But the present answer is at least mathematically correct, unlike the accepted one...

Answer (score 4):

You can go this way

> $$ \sqrt{8} \sqrt{i}=  \sqrt{8} e^{\frac{1}{2}\ln i}= \sqrt{8}\,e^{\frac{1}{2}\left(\ln|i|+i\left(\frac{\pi}{2}+2k\pi\right)\right)}= \sqrt{8}\,e^{\left(i(\frac{\pi}{4})+k\pi\right)},\quad k=0,1.$$

Note that, if you take $k=2,3,\dots$, then you go back to the same roots.

Comment: Using Log $i\;$ for such basic questions is pretty risky or even plain wrong: the complex logarithmic function is infinitely valued and unless one definite branch is chosen for it there is no way to tell what Log $i\;$ is, though I'm guessing you meant the usual branch deleting all the non-positive real axis. Anyway, it is higly doubtable someone asking this question can grasp all this.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @DonAntonio: See my answer to this [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/288673/branches-of-analytic-functions) which is related to what you said.

Comment: I was reading answers and thinking "What's happening? Why there isn't anyone with simple and clear trigonometric formula?". And here you are :)

Comment: @cdshines: Thank you for the comment. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Your bracketing is I think wrong in your final part of the equality (the i should be multiplying everything I think? and in the previous part its doing strange things with big and little brackets...

Comment: @Chris: Fixed. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 4):

The absolute value of $8i$ is $8$, so the absolute value of its square root is $\sqrt{8} = 2\sqrt{2}$.

The angle from the real axis to the imaginary axis (where $8i$ is located) is $90^\circ$, so the angle from the real axis to the ray on which $\sqrt{8i}$ is located is half of that: $45^\circ$.  Consequently it's a number of the form $a+ai$, where $a>0$.  The absolute value of $a+ai$ is $\sqrt{a^2+a^2} = a\sqrt{2}$.

So we have $a\sqrt{2} = 2\sqrt{2}$, so $a=2$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint :

> $$
> \sqrt i =  \frac1{\sqrt2}(1+i)
> $$

Answer (score 1):

First note that $(2+2i)^2=4-4+8i=8i$. Now to be exact $$\sqrt{8i}=2\sqrt{2}e^{i(2k+1)\pi/4}\tag{*}$$ where $k\in \{0,3\}$. So actually $\sqrt{8i}$ is multi-valued just as $\sqrt{8}=\pm 2\sqrt{2}$ is multi-valued.. The identity $(*)$ comes from a famous formula proved by Euler. You can learn more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula).

Comment: You can't have $4$ solutions... All solutions are roots of $X^2-8i$ which is of degree $2$ so you can have at most $2$ solutions... In fact, you can factor it as $(X+\alpha)(X-\alpha)$ for any $\alpha$ so that $\alpha^2 = 8i$.